# Can't run java application with .jar dependancy - 'Error: Could not find or load main class'

Tags: java, command-line, jar, classpath

So my code runs fine in my IDE and I have the `javax.mail.jar` set as a dependency and my code runs fine.

Except I need to use `Console console = System.console();`
and this does not work within IDE's

So I am trying to compile my code and run it via the terminal, I can compile although when running my code it returns the error:

> Error: Could not find or load main class Main

This is what I do to compile:

> javac -cp "./javax.mail.jar" Main.java

Then to run it:

> java -cp "./javax.mail.jar" Main

but I get the Error: Could not find or load main class Main

This is my full code:

```
package com.company;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Properties;
import javax.mail.Message;
import javax.mail.MessagingException;
import javax.mail.PasswordAuthentication;
import javax.mail.Session;
import javax.mail.Transport;
import javax.mail.internet.InternetAddress;
import javax.mail.internet.MimeMessage;

public class Main {
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {


    Properties props = new Properties();
    props.put("mail.smtp.host", "smtp.gmail.com");
    props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.port", "465");
    props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.class", "javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory");
    props.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");
    props.put("mail.smtp.port", "465");

    Session session = Session.getDefaultInstance(props,
            new javax.mail.Authenticator() {
                protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
                    return new PasswordAuthentication("TestEmail@gmail.com","pass");
                }
            });

    try {

        Message message = new MimeMessage(session);
        message.setFrom(new InternetAddress("TestEmail@gmail.com"));
        message.setRecipients(Message.RecipientType.TO, InternetAddress.parse("TestEmail@gmail.com"));
        message.setSubject("JavaMail");
        message.setText("Hi," + "\n\n This is a test");

        Transport.send(message);

        System.out.println("Sent!");


    } catch (MessagingException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
}


}
```

Edit:
Also tried running from parent directory(This has my com folder in and the `java.mail.jar`):

> java -cp "./javax.mail.jar;." com.company.Main

But I get this:

> Error: Could not find or load main class com.company.Main

Comment: `java -cp ./javax.mail.jar:. Main` otherwise, the directory where Main is is not in the classpath, hence the error. Storing class files in the same directory as jar files is a bad idea. Using the default package is also a bad idea.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You shall compile it from parent folder of com, by:

```
javac -cp "./javax.mail.jar:." com/company/Main.java
```

And then run by

```
java -cp "./javax.mail.jar:." com.company.Main
```

Comment: make sure the name of jar in command,  matches with the actual jar

Comment: oops please see edited answer, replace `;` with a `:` in classpath for mac

Comment: My saviour!! Thankyou so so much

Comment: Glad that helped you .. have fun coding :)

Answer (score 1):

```
java -cp ".;./javax.mail.jar" com.company.Main
```

Comment: Cheers :) very helpful

Answer (score -1):

You can use [java.util.Scanner][1]

[1]: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html class to accept the input from console instead of Console which is not useful in IDEs.

Other post have already answered how to compile the file from command line so not adding the duplicate detail.